# ClassNotFoundException: android.view.include

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle

I'm writing an Android unit test that tests that a Fragment launches an Activity with another Fragment in it. The activity layout looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/signup_finish_fragment"
        class="com.example.MyFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I launch the test, I get the following exception in the `inflater.inflate()` method:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.include
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
  at com.example.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:77)
```

What is the reason of this exception and how can I solve this problem? I haven't found any mentions of the `android.view.include` class in the official documentation.

UPD: here's the MyFragment layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/first_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/last_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/captcha_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@id/captcha"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
                <ProgressBar 
                    android:id="@id/captcha_progress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@id/refresh_captcha"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_signup_refresh"
                android:scaleType="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <EditText
            android:id="@id/captcha_code"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox 
            android:id="@id/agreement_checkbox"        
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/btn_check"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/agreement_link"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@id/done"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/done" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Since you appear to be inflating this layout in a fragment, and the layout contains a fragment, are you correctly using nested fragments?

Comment: Please show `MyFragment` layout.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not using nested fragments. I have two activities with one fragment inside each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

check whether you checked private libaries in `order and export` section of `java Build Path`,clean and build again

Comment: Couldn't find that window in Android Studio, but I don't think that's the issue. When I replace the `<fragment>` tag with `<TextView>` everything works fine. Also, I've added an additional dependency for the test project in `build.gradle` file (`instrumentTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'`), but it didn't help.